# Can't save InfoPath form when it has an error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I created a form and published it to a Document Library. (SharePoint 2010)

I set some rules on some fields. When the user didn't complete correctly the form he/she saw an error, but it allowed the user to save this form despite the error!!

I want that Document library not to save this form when users don't complete the form correctly.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried removing the Save option from the Ribbon bar at the top of the form and put a button somewhere on the form that will perform the save action when clicked. That way you can have a rule on the button to only show when they're are no errors and the user cannot click save until the form is error-free!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the fields mandatory by enabling this on fields properties or by making a validation rule that makes the form unable to being submitted when these validations happen.